# Speed of Angle of twist wave in a Torsion Bar subject to alternating torque

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

I am building a [Torsional Harmonic Oscillator](https://www.teachspin.com/torsional-oscillator) to measure the moment of inertia of an object mounted on its end.

I have a magnet and solenoid that inputs a torque of sinusoidal nature w.r.t. time to the middle of a shaft, and on the end of the shaft is my object.

After considering the problem as a 1D harmonic oscillator, it occurred to me that the angle of twist, which I was so keen on modelling varies with time and position along the tube, since it takes some time for this so-called, "wave of twist" to propagate down the shaft.

My question is: how fast does it move? Would the calculation be similar to calculating the speed of sound in a material (dependent on material bulk modulus and density)?